# How to get the link of the created server in the http.createServer() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get the link of the created server in the http.createServer() function?

I am trying to use the http package from node.js and use the createServer() function, then I want to print the server's link with the port, like this:

```js
const createServer = http.createServer();
const server = createServer.listen(port);
```

And then get the link from the `createServer` variable like `http://localhost` or from a repl.it/replit.com link
.
this is my code in JS:

```js
const port = 1234;
const createServer = http.createServer();
const server = createServer.listen(port);
const websocket = new web({ httpServer: server });

console.log(createServer); // This doesnt print the server link
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information about the server by calling `server.address()`:

```
console.dir(server.address());

//{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 1234 }
```

Since you didn't specify a `host` when creating the server, the default one will be used which according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback):

> If host is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (::) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (0.0.0.0) otherwise.

Comment: How about if i host it on replit? what would it supposedly return?

Comment: wherever you host it it's going to return the internal address used by the server, not the public url, that's a completely seperate thing which will depend greatly on your setup. i'm not familiar with Replit but it will most likely be a dynamic url generated on the fly, have a look at their [documentation](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/deploying-http-servers).

Comment: If i host it on replit, the server public url would show at the top of the site view with this format: `https://REPL-REPOSITORY-NAME.USER.repl.co`, so if i host on another server, it might not show the public url, so i want to know a way to be able to display it